# Delete action and destroy method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something like this in view:

```
<% if actions.include? "delete" %>
 <%= link_to 'Usuń', asset_path(asset), :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm =>   "Want to delete it?" }, :role => "link" %>
 <% end %>
```

and this in assetcontroller:

```
def destroy

@asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id])
@asset.destroy
redirect_to assets_path

end
```

the question is, why it "use" destroy method when action in view is "delete" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is method of HTTP protocol. `destroy` is the `action` of your `controller`. 
Route with `delete` HTTP method leads to `destroy` action.

To edit this routes and make `delete` HTTP method lead to `delete` action (for example), you should edit `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: hm but obj also have delete method ,how to use delete action then? i dont need it but i try to understand this

Comment: so the "default" action is destroy but i can route it by routes.rb to delete action ? Something like that ? :)

Comment: Yes, "Something like that". Rails RESTful convention is that `delete` method leads to `destroy` action, but it can be customized with `routes.rb` quite easily.

Comment: Thanks very much - czy może dzięki bo chyba Polak ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your routes.rb file you have defined the model as a resource (or a generator like scaffold did). This means that the default CRUD routes are generated. If you want to do it another way, use your own routes instead of generating them.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: yes i have resources in routes - thanks i must read about this

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions leave this for other destroy is there :)

Comment: Isn't this the very same link on my answer?